# Number format of a cell based on info given on an adjacent cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, cell-formatting, vba

Trying to set the number format of a cell based on the currency selected on an adjacent cell using VBA. See sample below.

[image]

So far I am using the below code but I cannot seem to make the format to appear properly

```
Option Explicit
Public preValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ccy As String

ccy = Range("A3").Value
pctFormat = "0.000%"
fxFormat = ccy + " " + pctFormat


If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> preValue And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

  Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).NumberFormat = fxFormat

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End If

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this option to set your `fxFormat variable`:

```
fxFormat = "[$" & ccy & "] 0.000%"
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps:

```
fxFormat = chr(34) & ccy & chr(34) & " " & pctFormat
```

Comment: this solution also works!. Is there a way that i can also give some answer credit to you?

Comment: I have no clue-I've only been here a couple days!

Comment: @macutan upvote away! That's credit just without the check mark